# How to use rep to copy values in R?

Tags: r

In R say that I have a df ordered by year and I have data only in one year as below.

```
year     data  num   code 
2011.1    b     31   DA
2011.2    a     35   2Q
2011.3    b     25   B3
2011.4    b     20   2F
2011.5    d     51   3H
2011.6    w     32   L2
2011.7    a     45   3B
2011.8    w     32   K1
2011.9    q     31   C3
2011.10   e     61   L9
2011.11   z     31   2K
2011.12   a     13   4K
2012.1    NA    NA   NA
2012.2    NA    NA   NA
...

2017.11
2017.12
```

I'd like to fill the rest of the other rows with the same values in 2011 in that case what code I need to write?

I've already tried the `rep()` function, but I guess it only has parameters like 1:12 for example, rep(1:12, times=7) which is what I DON'T want.

Answer (score 0):

Arrange using months then fill the missing with `tidyr::fill`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   arrange(substr(year,6,7)) %>% 
   tidyr::fill(-year,.direction='down') %>% 
   arrange(year)

    year data num code
1 2011.1    b  31   DA
2 2011.2    a  35   2Q
3 2011.3    b  25   B3
4 2011.4    b  20   2F
5 2011.5    d  51   3H
6 2012.1    b  31   DA
7 2012.2    a  35   2Q
8 2017.1    b  31   DA
9 2017.2    a  35   2Q
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Rows to be copied
M0 = df[1:12,]
# Start out empty
M = {}
# for loops are allowed :-)
for (i in 2011:2017) M = rbind(M, M0)
# Fix year column
M$year = df$year
# M holds the answer
```